# get values from a nested dictionary using lambda values of the dictionary are ArrayList of ArrayList

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, arraylist

I need to retrieve values from dictionary which stores a ArrayList which in turn has an ArrayList This second ArrayList has int array stored . Now how can I retrieve those integer values.   `

```
        Dictionary<int, ArrayList> obj = new Dictionary<int, ArrayList>();

        ArrayList objList1 = new ArrayList();

        ArrayList objList2 = new ArrayList();

        ArrayList objList3 = new ArrayList();

        Int32[] a1 = new Int32[5] {11, 21, 32, 43, 50 };
        Int32[] b1 = new Int32[5] { 123, 2321, 3212, 4983, 5760 };
        Int32[] c1 = new Int32[5] { 1341, 2991, 3552, 4663, 5880 };

        objList2.Add(a1);
        objList2.Add(b1);
        objList2.Add(c1);



        objList1.Add(objList2);
        objList1.Add(objList3);

        obj.Add(1, objList1);
        obj.Add(2, objList3);`
```

this could be done easily with List. I trying it solve with ArrayList. Firstly is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: questions stand alone on Stack Overflow. Write your entire question here. And note: that question was poorly specified. Try to include more detail here.

Comment: Working with ArrayList is relatively painful because it's nongeneric. Are you sure you can't use `List<T>` instead? It would be nice to see a sample so we know exactly what you've got and what you want the result to be.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: I edited my question please let me know if this is already asked.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yes It could be done easily with List<T> But for this scenario I working with ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
foreach(var item in obj.Values
    .SelectMany(x => x.Cast<ArrayList>())
    .SelectMany(x => x.Cast<int[]>())
    .SelectMany(x => x))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

output:

```
11
21
32
43
50
123
2321
3212
4983
5760
1341
2991
3552
4663
5880
```

Answer (score 0):

```
obj
   .SelectMany(x=>x.Value.Cast<ArrayList>())
   .SelectMany(x=>x.Cast<int[]>())
   .SelectMany(x=>x)
```